# Как во Vue правильно получить данные из Firebase (Cloud Firestore)

Tags: vue.js, firebase, firestore

Есть Vue проект (c Vuex), который я хочу совместить с Firebase (Cloud Firestore).
Я хочу один раз получить данные из Firebase при инициализации и дальше уже с ними работать. Ниже представлен код с помощью которого я это делаю. Данные я получаю, однако в консоли появляется ошибка. Если я правильно понимаю, то компонент постоянно перерендеривается. Как это исправить?

main.js (здесь я инициализирую Firebase)

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'
import store from './store'
import firebase from 'firebase'

firebase.initializeApp({
  apiKey: '...',
  authDomain: '...',
  databaseURL: '...',
  projectId: '...',
  storageBucket: '...',
  messagingSenderId: '...',
  appId: '...'
})
export const db = firebase.firestore()

Vue.config.productionTip = false

new Vue({
  router,
  store,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```

App.vue (здесь я вызываю action для получения данных из Firebase)

```js
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <router-view/>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'App',
  created () {
    this.$store.dispatch('FETCH_CARS')
  }
}
</script>
```

cars.js (является одним из модулей Vuex Store)

```js
import { db } from '../main'

export default {
  state: {
    cars: []
  },
  mutations: {
    LOAD_CARS (state, payload) {
      state.cars = payload
    }
  },
  actions: {
    async FETCH_CARS ({ commit }) {
      const resultCars = []
      try {
        await db.collection('cars').get().then((querySnapshot) => {
          querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
            resultCars.push(doc.data())
          })
          commit('LOAD_CARS', resultCars)
        })
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error.message)
        throw error
      }
    }
  },
  getters: {
    getCarsSortByYear: (state) => state.cars.sort(function (a, b) {
      return a.year - b.year
    }),
    getCarsReversYear: (state) => state.cars.sort(function (a, b) {
      return b.year - a.year
    })
  }
}
```

ListCars (компонент в котором я вывожу данные)

```js
<template>
  <div class="hello">
    <h1>Список автомобилей</h1>
    <ul>
      <li v-for="car in getCarsSortByYear" :key="car.name">
        <h3>{{car.name}}</h3>
        <span>{{car.year}}</span><br>
        <span>{{car.color}}</span>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <li v-for="car in getCarsReversYear" :key="car.year">
        <h3>{{car.name}}</h3>
        <span>{{car.year}}</span><br>
        <span>{{car.color}}</span>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</template>

<script>

import { mapGetters } from 'vuex'

export default {
  name: 'ListCars',
  computed:
    mapGetters([
      'getCarsSortByYear',
      'getCarsReversYear'
    ])
}

</script>
```

console

```js
[Vue warn]: You may have an infinite update loop in a component render function.

found in

---> <ListCars> at src/components/ListCars.vue
       <Home> at src/views/Home.vue
         <App> at src/App.vue
           <Root>
```

Answer (score 1):

Проблема, как показали опыты, в конкретных геттерах. Если их использовать по отдельности или не использовать вообще. К примеру, если просто получить весь массив "cars"

```
getCarsList: (state) => state.cars
```

то вышеуказанная ошибка не появляется.

Если кто-то объяснит почему такое происходит, то буду очень благодарен.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема была в том, что метод sort() изменяет исходный массив. Из-за этого данные постоянно изменялись и компонент бесконечно перерендеривался. Поэтому если использовать данный метод, то надо работать с копией массива, а не с исходным.